# FuelPHP - pre_save() on model not working

Tags: fuelphp

Does anyone knows how to get `pre_save()` or `pre_validate()` to work in my model?
 I have the code below in the model, but it is never called.

```
protected function pre_validate($data)
{
    //die("asefeg");
    $data->idRegistrant = Session::get('idRegistrant', null);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: My BaseModel extends \Orm\Model and pre_save only work for classes that extends \Crud\Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORM does not have a `pre_save()` method like the CRUD model does. For this functionality you want to look into implementing an observer. Plenty of info can be found about this in the [fuelphp docs](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/observers/creating.html)